# How to change cell value repeatedly by entering the value in other cell or sheet?

Tags: excel, if-statement, data-manipulation

I want to create a roster in excel-sheet using 3 resources( resource 1, resource 2 and resource 3) into 2 shifts.
Now I want, when I enter resource 1 in some other cell this value should be copied to shift column. Here is sample data and you would be able to understand what is required.[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZU9p.png)

Comment: Can anyone please help out

Comment: Your questions isn't clear.  You say "when I enter resource 1 in some other cell" but what is the "other cell" you are talking about.  It's not clear from your screengrab.

Also to auto-copy as your desire will need some VBA code running on the sheet in the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`.   TIP: in the code use an IF statement of the form `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D7:D23")) Is Nothing Then ....  End If` so it only runs when the change is made in the range you want copied.

Comment: Hi @tjejojyj,
I have provided the sample data to use these resource and here is the explanation what help I need, please help as soon as possible:
http://imgur.com/aY3OqoD

Comment: Looking at you spreadsheet you  don't have a perpetual calendar but a chronological one and all you are seeking to do is get the second shift to always follow the first in a standard sequence  1=>2=>3=>1.     Why don't you just build a small lookup table so the sequence is indicated 1,2|2,3|3,1 then use a VLOOKUP in your column C to read the resource for the next shift?     Or, even simpler, something like this in column C `="Resource-"&CHOOSE(RIGHT(B:B,1),2,3,1)`?

Comment: Hi @tjejojyj,
Thank you for your response, you got it right. Can you please help me with an example here how to achieve this. Sorry I am not much familiar with excel commands.

It's a single sheet file, can you please just show me with a screenshot that which value needs to put where.

Thank you again!

Comment: put the formula `="Resource-"&CHOOSE(RIGHT(B:B,1),2,3,1)` into cell C2, just under the header, then fill down.     Just to explain what its doing: RIGHT(B:B,1) takes the resource number off the adjacent cell in column B then CHOOSE(index_num,value1,value2,value3) returns the value according to that number.  If 1 then 2, if 2 then 3, if 3 then 1.    Otherwise I will post an "answer" using VLOOKUP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit J1:J4 as per the image below ...

[image]

and fill down the following formula from C2

```
=VLOOKUP(B:B,$I$1:$J$4,2,0)
```